# Write non-Unicode using csv module

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, encoding, stringio

While migrating to Python 3, I noticed some files we generate using the built-in `csv` now have `b'` prefix around each strings...

Here's the code, that should generate a .csv for a list of `dogs`, according to some parameters defined by `export_fields` (thus always returns unicode data):

```
file_content = StringIO()
csv_writer = csv.writer(
    file_content, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
)
csv_writer.writerow([
    header_name.encode('cp1252') for _v, header_name in export_fields
])
# Write content
for dog in dogs:
    csv_writer.writerow([
        get_value(dog).encode('cp1252') for get_value, _header in export_fields
    ])
```

The problem is once I returns `file_content.getvalue()`, I get:

```
b'Does he bark?'    b'Full     Name'    b'Gender'
b'Sometimes, yes'   b'Woofy the dog'    b'Male'
```

Instead of <sup><sub>(indentation has been modified to be readable on SO)</sub></sup>:

```
'Does he bark?'   'Full     Name'   'Gender'
'Sometimes, yes'  'Woofy the dog'   'Male'
```

I did not find any `encoding` parameter in the `csv` module. I would like the whole file to be encoded in cp1252, so I don't really care either the encoding is done through the iteration of the lines or on the file construted itself.

So, does anyone know how to generate a proper string, containing only cp1252 encoded strings?

Comment: Why are you encoding in the first place? The open file object takes care of that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Maybe my question is incomplete then: I want to return the string through Django: `return HttpResponse(generate_csv_file())`. Should I handle encoding at Django level instead?

Comment: See my answer; you are approaching this at the wrong level; tabs and quotechars need to be encoded too, but this is the job of the I/O level, not the `csv` module or the code producing rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `csv` module deals with *text*, and converts anything that is not a string to a string using `str()`.

Don't pass in `bytes` objects. Pass in `str` objects or types that cleanly convert to strings with `str()`. That means you *should not encode strings*.

If you need `cp1252` output, encode the `StringIO` value:

```
file_content.getvalue().encode('cp1252')
```

as `StringIO` objects also deal in text only.

Better yet, use a [`BytesIO` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) with a [`TextIOWrapper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) to do the encoding for you as the `csv` module writes to the file object:

```
from io import BytesIO, TextIOWrapper

file_content = BytesIO()
wrapper = TextIOWrapper(file_content, encoding='cp1252', line_buffering=True)
csv_writer = csv.writer(
    wrapper, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

# write rows

result = file_content.getvalue()
```

I've enabled line-buffering on the wrapper so that it'll auto-flush to the `BytesIO` instance every time a row is written.

Now `file_content.getvalue()` produces a bytestring:

```
>>> from io import BytesIO, TextIOWrapper
>>> import csv
>>> file_content = BytesIO()
>>> wrapper = TextIOWrapper(file_content, encoding='cp1252', line_buffering=True)
>>> csv_writer = csv.writer(wrapper, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
>>> csv_writer.writerow(['Does he bark?', 'Full     Name', 'Gender'])
36
>>> csv_writer.writerow(['Sometimes, yes', 'Woofy the dog', 'Male'])
35
>>> file_content.getvalue()
b'Does he bark?\tFull     Name\tGender\r\nSometimes, yes\tWoofy the dog\tMale\r\n'
```

Comment: Looks like it works with the wrapper indeed (once flushed, but you made the edit before I has the time to comment). Tests passed so 99% sure it is the right answer :)

Comment: @MaximeLorant: I've now switched it to using line-buffering; avoids having to manually flush. Sorry about that.

Comment: Seems cleaner indeed! Thanks for the tip.